# Internet Explorer blank page start

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, command-line-arguments

You know that it is a slow browser (probably it is not already but I am still using W7). It is mainly because it loads a lot of stuff during start up.

There are guidelines how to set up "`about:blank`" from the `Internet Options`. It helps but I remember that there was a stronger, command line argument for doing that. Because blank page still loaded some libraries whereas command line option enabled almost instant start.

Comment: I fail to see a question here at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Run using <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and then type:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\IEXPLORE.EXE" -nohome
```

Or if that wasn't what you wanted try:

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"  -extoff
```